# Rail UJS with json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ujs

In my javascript response to a form that was submitted with `data-remote=true`, I have this line:

```
my_function("<%=@object.to_json%>")
```

But the arg passed to `my_function` is filled with `&quot;`, which my javascript fails to interpret as an object.  I assume I need to escape `<%=@object.to_json%>` somehow, but I don't know which javascript function to use.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default everything you write to template using `<%= %>` is escaped. To prevent Rails from doing that you can use [`raw`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw) helper:

```
my_function("<%= raw @object.to_json %>")
```